# How to load a div containing HTML on close of jQuery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On close I have to load a `<div>`, because my HTML is loaded in the `<div>`.

i.e.

```
window.location.href =  $("#bodydiv").load('pages/test1.html');
```

But this actually does not work the way we want because the `<div>` that loads HTML is not actually a `.html` page.

How can I do this?

Code:

```
function test_() {
    var dDialog = $('#test1').load("pages/test.html");
    dDialog.dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        title: "Warning",
        buttons: [{
            text: "Ok",
            click: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }],
        close: function (event, ui) {
            /* want to load this way but this does not (will not) work   */
            window.location.href = $("#bodyDiv").load('pages/test1.html');
        }
    });
    dDialog.dialog('open');
}
```

If I just give `window.location.href = "pages/test1.html"`, the HTML is loaded as expected, but not within the `<div>` I specify, along with the styles for that `<div>`.

Comment: Have you try with an `$("#div").append(//html code);` ?

Answer (score 0):

window.location.href will change the URL of the window to the URL specified. If you just want to inject HTML to the div specified, remove the window.location.href altogether, that should just inject the HTML to bodyDiv.

Comment: Hey had tried that already dude .. But in that case the dialog does not get opened after closed and triggered again. Receiving error TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish on close? Inject new HTML into the same dialog?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want window.location.ref, that changes the page.  You just want  $("#bodyDiv").load('pages/test1.html');.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

function test_() {
    var dDialog = $('#dialog');
    dDialog.dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        title: "Warning",
        buttons: [{
            text: "Ok",
            click: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }],
        close: function (event, ui) {
            $("#bodyDiv").load('/');
        }
    });
    dDialog.dialog('open');
}

test_();
})
```

Assuming the following html:

```
<div id='bodyDiv'>Hi there </div>
<div id='dialog'>Some Dialog</div>
```

look at this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/WJj63/)